# Django - Annotate post query set data with if current user has "liked" the post

Tags: python, django

So I have this model

`model.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=generate_ulid_as_uuid, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator")
    body = models.CharField(max_length=POST_MAX_LEN, validators=[MinLengthValidator(POST_MIN_LEN)])

class LikePost(AbstractSimpleModel):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="like_post")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

class User(AbstractDatesModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=USERNAME_MAX_LEN, unique=True, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(USERNAME_MIN_LEN)])
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then I also have this annotator for returning a bunch of data outside of the Post table

`annotator.py`

```
def query_to_full_post_data_serializer(post_query_set: QuerySet):
    query_set_annotated = post_query_set.annotate(
        creator_username=F('creator__username'),
        user_liked=F(<flag for each post in query for if user liked the post>)
        reply_count=Count('postreply', distinct=True),
        like_count=Count('likepost', distinct=True),
    ).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('photo', Photo.objects.order_by('-created')),
        Prefetch('video', Video.objects.order_by('-created'))
    )
    return FullPostDataSerializer(query_set_annotated, many=True)
```

I'd like to return a field called "user_liked", which returns a boolean for each post in a query set that is `True` if the current logged in user has liked it or is the `creator` of a `LikePost` to a `Post`. When the request comes in I get the current user making the request so I can get their `uuid`. I'd like to use that uuid to check if the user has liked a post in the query set. **How do I check if the current logged in user has liked a `Post` object in a query set Django?**

I'm assuming you can do something like `user_liked=F('likepost', filter=creator__uuid=current_user_uuid)`, but that wouldn't be a boolean that'd return user. If I really wanted I could do `user_liked=Count('likepost, filter=creator__uuid=current_user_uuid)` seems kind of inefficient though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my previous wrong answer.

So I'm quite rusty in the Django ORM so that query might not have best optimisation. Here is what I have come up with

```
Post.objects.all().annotate(liked_by_user=Q(likepost__creator=user))
```

The issue being that it will add duplicates for each reverse relationship it finds. That's why you should not use that and use a many to many.

For example, with a many to many, it would be as simple as

```
class User2(models.Model):
    _id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    

class Post2(models.Model):
    _id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    creators = models.ManyToManyField(User2)
```

and now you only need

```
Post2.object.all().annotate(liked_by_user=Q(creator__in=[user]))
```

which is way better.

Comment: what do you mean "add duplicates"? I think these annotations you're writing up return either a `LikePost` object or a list of them not a boolean, no? My rational is that `Q` is for querying so you're essentially filtering `LikePost` where the `creator` is equal to some uuid or in a list of uuid.

Comment: @user8714896 the issue is that for each Post, there might be multiple LikePost, so for each LikePost of the post, you will get an extra row. So for example, is you have us1 and us2 who liked post, for that post you'll have one like representing us1 which gives you True if us1 is logged and an additional line for us2 for the same post which gives you False, so you will have to combine the lines by doing a groupby and a big or

Comment: your post says don't use a many-to-many then you said with a "many-to-many it would be as simple as" could you be more explicit? It's not really clear what you're referring to with the first many-to-many and the second many-to-many.

Comment: also would the filter then count solution I put in my question post cover the issue you've described?

Comment: assuming that the `creator` and `post` are unique together in the `LikePost` table that query is not going to produce any duplicates. Although for efficiency it would be best to use [Exists() subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries). Also @user8714896 might have some extra data with that many to many (since they inherit from an abstract model), they should specify that model as the [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) though.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat `Exists` looks like what I need, but doesn't seem like I can set it within `annotate` function. I tried `is_liked_by_user=Exists('cheerpost', filter=Q(creator=uuid))` and it threw an error. I'm assuming can't use sub-queries in this way.

Comment: @user8714896 you need to pass a _queryset_ to `Exists`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat is there a way to add it to the `annotate` function in `query_to_full_post_data_serializer` above?